# Курсор в Oracle

Tags: oracle, база-данных

Объясните мне понятие курсора в Oracle. Лучше с примером.
Чем это отличается от процедуры?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**КУРСОР** - это указатель (хотя как такового, понятия "указатель" в PL/SQL нет!) на контекстную область памяти, с помощью которого программа на языке PL/SQL может управлять контекстной областью и ее состоянием во время обработки оператора.

Объявление курсора определяет какое выражение языка SQL - будет передано программе SQL Statement Executor (системе исполнителю выражения SQL). Курсор может представлять собой любое допустимое предложение языка SQL! Так же, курсор является основным базовым "кирпичиком" для построения блоков PL/SQL. Курсоры обеспечивают циклический механизм оперирования наборами данных в БД. Курсор может возвращать одну или несколько строк данных или вообще ни одной.

В PL/SQL поддерживаются два типа курсоров: явные и неявные. Явный курсор объявляется разработчиком, а неявный курсор не требует объявления.

Курсор может возвращать одну строку, несколько строк или ни одной строки. Для запросов, возвращающих более одной строки, можно использовать только явный курсор. Для повторного создания результирующего набора для других значений параметров курсор следует закрыть, а затем повторно открыть.

Курсор может быть объявлен в секциях объявлений любого блока PL/SQL, подпрограммы(процедуры или функции) или пакета.

Comment: копирайты не забываем ставить! [www.ПЕРВЫЕ ШАГИ.ru](http://www.firststeps.ru/sql/oracle/r.php?52)

Comment: тут только частично взято с первых шагов... от себя добавил еще...